# Access outputto report to pdf with selection: selection sometimes wrong

Tags: ms-access, pdf, vba

I've got a database that exports invoices to pdf and mails them, using the outputto command for generating the invoices. I've got the outputto in a function that takes the name of the invoice report (strRptName), the filter on invoice number (stropenargs) and the filename containing the invoice number (strFilename) and returns the filename of the PDF if it could be generated.

```
Public Function PDFRpt(strRptName As String, strFileName As String, strOpenArgs As String) As String

    DoCmd.OpenReport strRptName, acViewPreview, , , acHidden, strOpenArgs
    If Reports(strRptName).HasData Then
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strRptName, acFormatPDF, strFileName & ".pdf", False
        PDFRpt = strFileName & ".pdf"
    Else
        PDFRpt = "Nodata"
    End If
    DoCmd.Close acReport, strRptName

End function
```

In the print and mail subroutine, I loop through the invoice headers calling this function. Filename and filter variables are filled in the loop, obviously using the same invoice number from the recordset.

This usually works, but occasionally, the contents of the pdf don't match up with the filter. For example: the filename says it contains invoice number 149, but if you open the pdf, it shows invoice number 153. There is a file with 153 in the name, that also contains invoice number 153.

I suppose it's transient conditions on the network that cause this hiccough, but is there any way I can prevent it? Perhaps using other code to create the pdf's?

Hope that someone can throw some light on this problem. Thanks in advance.

Ingrid

Comment: If truly random <groan>; do some of the pdf's contain multiple invoices? How about grabbing the query that selects the data, change it to select 149 and 153 and then stare at the fields returned to see if anything looks weird or missing. Just guessing...

Comment: Yes, truly random...last time it went wrong was two months ago; since then no problems up to last week. There is no difference between 149 and 153, or any of the in-betweens.